# Preventing duplicate results in a joined fulltext search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, distinct

I have two tables which are post and info and each post can have multiple rows of info.

The table structure looks like this,

```
post (int id, int published, varchar title)

info (int id, text content, int post_id)
```

I want to make a simple fulltext search inside info, and return a list of posts, but I want a post row to only show up once in the list of results even if it finds the query text inside info multiple times,

My current query looks like this, but it still returns multiple post rows with the same id,

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(post.id),
    post.title,
    info.content
FROM
    post, info
WHERE 
    info.post_id = post.id 
    AND published = 1
    AND MATCH(info.content) AGAINST('cucumber')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql distinct clause work for rows  and not for single column value

if you need  just a result you should use aggregation function and group by

```
    SELECT 
        post.id,
        min(post.title),
        min(info.content)
    FROM post
    INNER  info ON  info.post_id = post.id 
        AND published = 1
    WHERE MATCH(info.content) AGAINST('cucumber')
    group by post.id
```